# I'm having trouble with lists

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to write a spellchecker that tells you which words in the sentence are spelled incorrectly.
It's supposed to read a specific sentence from an input and see if the words in that sentence are part of the list given. If they are not part, it should print the words that are out of place. If everything is correct, it should print "OK". I'm having trouble however with getting it to print ONLY the incorrect words, and not to loop through the whole list and print OK several times.

This is my code so far:

```
dictionary = ['all', 'an', 'and', 'as', 'closely', 'correct', 'equivocal',
              'examine', 'indication', 'is', 'means', 'minutely', 'or', 'scrutinize',
              'sign', 'the', 'to', 'uncertain']

sentence = input()
sentence = sentence.split()

for word in sentence:
    if word not in dictionary:
        print(word)
    elif word in dictionary:
        print("OK")
        break
```

Comment: Have a think through the current code; it loops through each word in the sentence, and generates a print statement for each word.  If this is not the expected output, think about how the code should be restructured.  Suggestion: draw a small flow diagram of the design, then write the code from that.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you use `break` when you see an incorrect word. This means it stops the loop where it is, and therefore does not find the other incorrect words.

The code you want looks like this:

```py
dictionary = ['all', 'an', 'and', 'as', 'closely', 'correct', 'equivocal',
              'examine', 'indication', 'is', 'means', 'minutely', 'or', 'scrutinize',
              'sign', 'the', 'to', 'uncertain']

sentence = input()
sentence = sentence.split()

found_incorrect_word = False
for word in sentence:
    if word not in dictionary:
        print(word)
        found_incorrect_word = True  # no break here
        
if not found_incorrect_word:
    print("OK")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are breaking out the minute you a correct word. Try this:

```
dictionary = ['all', 'an', 'and', 'as', 'closely', 'correct', 'equivocal',
              'examine', 'indication', 'is', 'means', 'minutely', 'or', 'scrutinize',
              'sign', 'the', 'to', 'uncertain']

sentence = input()
sentence = sentence.split()

incorrect = False
for word in sentence:
    if word not in dictionary:
        print(word)
        incorrect = True


if not incorrect:
    print("OK")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension to detect incorrect words

```
dictionary = ['all', 'an', 'and', 'as', 'closely', 'correct', 'equivocal',
              'examine', 'indication', 'is', 'means', 'minutely', 'or', 'scrutinize',
              'sign', 'the', 'to', 'uncertain']

sentence = input('Enter sentence: ')
sentence = sentence.split()
incorrect_words = [word for word in sentence if not word in dictionary]

if incorrect_words:
    print(*incorrect_words, sep='\n')
else:
    print('All words OK')
```

Or more succinctly

```
incorrect_words = [word for word in input('Enter sentence: ').split() if not word in dictionary]

if incorrect_words:
    print(*incorrect_words, sep='\n')
else:
    print('All words OK')
```